# How do you create a hollow physicsbody?(Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

So I am trying to create a soccer goal using sprite kit, and I want the inside of the goal to be hollow. How can I do that?

Comment: I am pretty new to ios so I need some help on this :)

Comment: 2d physics body or 3d physics body

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want a top-down representation of a goal, with nets to the sides and the rear, like this:

[image]

(so that's a top view, with the goal mouth facing down)

You can't do this with a single physics body, (with the physics body exactly following the nets) as physics bodies can't be concave.

Instead, create the 2 sides and the rear with their own physics bodies, and then join them together using `init(bodies: [SKPhysicsBody])`

e.g. assuming you have 3 sprite nodes, named goalRightSide, goalLeftSide and goalRear, each with their own physics body. Then, to create a compound physics body for thw whole goal, use:

```
let goalPB = SKPhysicsbody(bodies: [goalRightSide.physicsBody,
                                    goalLeftSide .physicsBody,
                                    goalRear.physicsBody])
```

Refer to the class reference for more details : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody

Comment: You can do this with a single physics body using `CGPath` and `SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom:)`.  What `init(bodies: [SKPhysicsBody]` actually does is merge the various bodies paths together into 1 path to form 1 polygon

Comment: Weird that documents say `polygonFrom:` is a convex polygon,  I am using it to make concave shapes,

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I thought that although you could create concave bodies, the contact/collision detection went all wrong. Its yours working?

Comment: I have not had any issues with it,  I am going to have to test it